# ExtJS Grid does not recognise deslected row

Tags: extjs, extjs4

If I use CTRL-Click to select rows in a grid it works fine.

However when I use CTRL-Click to DESELECT rows the selection model is showing information that IMO is incorrect.

In the following code :

```
grid.addListener('itemclick', function(selModel, record){

    Util.logInfo('itemclick  ')
    var rows = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    if (rows) {
        Util.logInfo('number sel : ' + rows.length)
    }
});
```

If I click two rows then I get

**number sel 2**

But if I then CTRL-Click a row (so that only one row is selected), an itemclick event is created, but I still get :

**number sel 2**

Is there something I am missing about the grid event/selection model?

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/e6gwbn16/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itemclick fires when an item **is clicked**.

You need to use [selectionchange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-selectionchange)

```
v.addListener('selectionchange', function(selModel, record){
...
});
```

---

[I update your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6gwbn16/2/)

---